# node.js не выполняет js файл, а открывает его в редакторе

Tags: node.js, gulp, sass

При попытке ввести команду `gulp sass` в node command prompt файл `gulp.js` не выполняется, а открывается в редакторе.

В файле следующий код:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('./SASS/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./SASS'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас не правильно назван конфигурационный файл gulp, по умолчанию он должен называться `gulpfile.js`. Переименуйте `gulp.js` в `gulpfile.js`.
Доказательство: [gulp getting started](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) четвертый пункт.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Мое утверждение основано на том, что в вопросе написано "файл gulp.js не выпоняется". Из этого я сделал вывод, что скорее всего неправильно назван конфигурационный файл gulp. По умолчанию конфигурационный gulp файл должен называться gulpfile.js. Ответ исправил, так хорошо?